# how to change country of sale in app store

Tags: iphone, app-store

hi my app appears in US store, however it is dominantly an australian app. how to make it appear in australian app store instead of US app store, however i can still search app in aus app store but wanna make it more visible in aus store.

thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To change the stores that your app appears in, log into iTunesConnect and click "Manage Your Apps." Select your app and click the "Rights and Pricing" button. You can select the stores you want from this page. (If you see a line at the bottom that says "Unless you select specific stores...", your app is already for sale in all stores.)

Comment: this is correct however this will only restrict app to a store, what i thought was making my app special for aus and also available for everyone.

Comment: Is there a way I can restrict the app to only one store (say US store)? The behavior I want is that people from other countries can search the app but cannot download it by simply switching stores. Is this possible?

Comment: `Manage Your Apps.` does not show up

Comment: @alper The original question and this answer are from 2011. Things have changed a lot in the App Store over the last 9 years.

Comment: Sorry I did not check the date of the answer. I think they closed option to change the store through `iTunesConnect `