# Is it possible to restrict download of a free iPhone app to specific countries?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I need to be able to restrict the downloading from the app store of a free app we have designed, so that the downloading facility is available only in specific countries. If this is not possible, would it be possible to specifically exclude use of the app from certain coordinates, e.g. the whole of North America?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can restrict the availability of your iPhone application in iTunes Connect during the submission process. See page 43 of the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf) (PDF):

> By default, the app will be available in all countries the App Store currently supports, unless you specifically select individual countries/stores. You can choose individual countries by selecting each box.

Answer (score 1):

This previous answer might be helpful.

[how to change country of sale in app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348365/how-to-change-country-of-sale-in-app-store)

Answer (score 1):

When you submit the app to Apple you can define what stores the app is available in. However, it may be possible for the user to download the app from another country's/region's store. When the app is running you may want to see if IP assigned to the device is located in a region you don't want the app to appear in. This isn't foolproof either.